# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localcdn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, hosts, windows-11

when I am running npm start facing below error

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localcdn
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:26) {
errno: -3008,
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'localcdn'
}
```

I already update my /etc/hosts file with 127.0.0.1 localcdn

Can anyone help me on that.